# PHP: Something is wrong in my IF statement?

Tags: php

I have my `$_SESSION['ugid']=1`.But why it still falls into the IF block?
Something wrong with my condition statement?

```
if(($_SESSION['ugid']!="1")||($_SESSION['ugid']!="2"))
{
    $_SESSION['error']="access";
    header("location:../error.php"); 
}
```

Comment: The real question is if they should be able to enter that code block at all if `($_SESSION['ugid'] == "1")`. Cause if so, then simply changing it to an AND statement isn't the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because you are using an OR condition.

`if(($_SESSION['ugid']!="1")||($_SESSION['ugid']!="2"))`

This reads as

`if session variable 1 doesn't equal 1 **OR** session 2 variable doesn't equal 2`

Clearly, session 2 variable is not equal to 2, therefore you are entering this code block.

Answer (score 1):

Use && instead of ||

```
if(($_SESSION['ugid']!="1")&&($_SESSION['ugid']!="2"))
{
    $_SESSION['error']="access";
    header("location:../error.php"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because if it's 1 it's still different than 2 (because of the OR). I think you meant to put `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
if(($_SESSION['ugid']!=1)||($_SESSION['ugid']!=2))
{
    $_SESSION['error']="access";
    header("location:../error.php"); 
}
```

Comment: "1" == 1 evaluates to true in php. How would your answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe having the value of your session as double qouted. Try removing it :)

Comment: "1" == 1 evaluates to true in php. How would your answer help?

Answer (score 0):

if you have an if statement like this:

```
if ( expr1 || expr2 ) {
    // do something
}
```

And the first condition, `expr1` is false, then PHP will evaluate the second condition. In this case, $_SESSION['ugid'] != "2" is `true`, so it executes the code in the if block.

The answer depends on what you're trying to do. If `1` or `2` are the only valid values (i.e. anything other than those values is an error in your application), then you could replace your `||` with an `&&`. I think it might read a bit nicer to do something like this:

```
$valid_guids = array(1, 2);
if ( !in_array($_SESSION['guid'], $valid_guids) ) {
    // Error code
}
```